# Soft body plasticity using Bullet Physics

Tags: bullet-physics, soft-body-dynamics

I made this post on the Bullet forum([link](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=11217)), but the forum is slow so I'm just copying the text from there.

Hello,

I'm currently working on a game and I want to make certain surfaces of the game world deformable by the user. I've already implemented soft bodies and mouse picking but I cant get the surfaces to stop returning to their original shape.

I should note that I use joints to keep the soft bodies stationary.

Does anyone know which settings I need to play with to get the desired effect? I'm very new to soft bodies so I don't understand a lot of the terms in the source code.

If bullet does not have the capabilities I need, does anyone know where I can read up on the topic and soft bodies in general?